# Designer based workflows issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have created a basic workflow that will duplicate an item(InfoPath form) and I set it to start manually. Everything is working fine for me, but when I ask other Site collection admins to test, they get start over message. If I give it site owners, they cant even see the manual start option in the workflows sections

However, mine and other workflows are working correctly if they are started automatically.

Any one faced this issue before?